# Opening tree graph

Tags: opening, memorization

I found this tree and found it an excellent visualisation:

[image: Sicilian]

Could anyone provide me with a graph that includes all common chess openings but to a lesser depth?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If this helps, I'm developing an interactive tree graph with chess traps and openings at http://www.chesstree.net. Currently, it shows common openings, how often they are used, and their win-loss ratios. You can also search openings and save your custom openings with comments. It also has a batch of traps in it, although their presentation is yet somewhat unrefined.

Comment: I like it, but I cannot scroll to see the full extent of the tree.

Comment: You can grab and drag the tree around.

Comment: That's a really cool app. I would recommend making the move percentages to be relative to that ply, rather than the absolute frequency.

Comment: @NathanFD Thanks! You're right; I switched the percentages as relative.

Comment: It's really hard to use it on mobile

Comment: That is actually awesome!

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps you were looking for something like this: http://www.chessfornovices.com/chessopeningsconclusion.html

Comment: This is a great resource. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 12):

If your search is still ongoing, I have a chess tree with all the openings for you. There is also printable pdf version on https://named-openings-galore.com/

[image: chess tree of main opening systems]

Answer (score 9):

You can build your own with e.g. a mind map tool (http://www.xmind.net/) together with a complete listing of chess openings (e.g. at http://www.chess.com/openings/).