# How do you document your opening repertoire on a mac?

Tags: opening, software, preparation

I have an opening repertoire which I play consistently. My problem, however, is that occasionally I will find holes in my repertoire: main line variations for which I have zero prep. I'd like to make my repertoire air-tight. As in, I would like to fill these gaps in my knowledge of theory.

My Idea is to thoroughly document, and scribe my repertoire. In doing this, I should clearly be able to see where my knowledge of theory is lacking and devote extra effort into learning those lines/ middlegame plans/ structures etc.

The problem, however, is that I can't find any software which would allow me to do precisely this. My computer is a mac, and so I cant use programs like chessbase or bookup. I have attempted to write out all the lines in a word processor, but it becomes extremely difficult to keep my lines organized, and I also cannot easily see the position on a board.

If anyone knows of a good solution I would be ecstatic to hear.

Comment: Did you try [SCID for Mac](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scidvspc/files/mac-64bit-unsupported/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use Graphviz ( either in the [online editor](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_0%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%3B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3Dlightgrey%3B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bstyle%3Dfilled%2Ccolor%3Dwhite%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20a0%20-%3E%20a1%20-%3E%20a2%20-%3E%20a3%3B%0A%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22process%20%231%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_1%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bstyle%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20b0%20-%3E%20b1%20-%3E%20b2%20-%3E%20b3%3B%0A%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22process%20%232%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3Dblue%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20start%20-%3E%20a0%3B%0A%20%20start%20-%3E%20b0%3B%0A%20%20a1%20-%3E%20b3%3B%0A%20%20b2%20-%3E%20a3%3B%0A%20%20a3%20-%3E%20a0%3B%0A%20%20a3%20-%3E%20end%3B%0A%20%20b3%20-%3E%20end%3B%0A%0A%20%20start%20%5Bshape%3DMdiamond%5D%3B%0A%20%20end%20%5Bshape%3DMsquare%5D%3B%0A%7D) or [downloadable software](http://www.graphviz.org/download/). You can create a flowchart with all moves and transpositions, here is an example : [image: Sample Sicilian Repertoire] [This](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29189/creating-a-opening-lines-book-in-tree-like-format) is an excellent answer which explains how to use it. If you have difficulty in visualize moves without the board, you can add screenshots of important position in the flowchart. Lichess study, as the other answer points out, is also a good alternative.

Answer (score 6):

A lichess study would be a good way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is with chesstempo.com, their opening tool is incredibly useful!

Answer (score 1):

I used to use [xChess](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xchess/) on my Mac. It's a GUI, which allows you to input variations and comments to your heart's content. And also to use an engine.

That's pretty much the extent of it, but definitely easier then writing lines into an text editor.